# Split string by size(1024 bytes)

Tags: python, split

I have opened a picture file and saved on a variable.

```
     file_input = open(FILE_PATH, 'rb')
     file_doc = file_input.read()
```

How can I split the variable to a list by size(each part of the list is the size of 1024 bytes)?

Comment: `while f: data = f.read(1024)`?

Answer (score 3):

You can split a bytes object just by indexing the corresponding slice, e.g.

```
>>> x = b'aabbcc'
>>> [x[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(x)-1,2)]
[b'aa', b'bb', b'cc']
```

But in general, I'd agree with @COLDSPEED: just read the file in chunks of 1024 bytes and do whatever you need with each chunk:

```
with open(FILE_PATH, "rb") as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(1024)
        if not data: break
        process_1k_bytes(data)
```